# Reducing a DataFrame with many rows per subject to one row per subject

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame which has multiple rows per subject. Each row is an adverse event experienced by a subject as well as a flag indicating if that particular adverse event was related, severe, or sae:

```
subject_id    related   severe   sae
05-218         True     False    False
05-218         True     True     False
05-218         False    False    False
05-010         False    False    False
05-010         True     False    False
05-010         True     False    False
05-010         False    False    False
```

What I'm trying to end up with is a resulting data frame which has one row per subject indicating if that subject **ever** experienced a related, severe or sae. Resulting in something like this:

```
subject_id    related    severe   sae
05-218         True      True     False
05-010         True      False    False
```

I'm stumped as to what to do! Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `max`

```
df.groupby('subject_id',as_index=False).max()
Out[357]: 
  subject_id  related  severe    sae
0     05-010     True   False  False
1     05-218     True    True  False
```

Comment: This worked, only thing was to method chain `.reset_index()`. So the complete line would be `df.groupby('subject_id').max().reset_index()`. Thanks!

Comment: @TheCuriouslyCodingFoxah updated not need `reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df = df.groupby('subject_id', sort=False).any()
print (df)
            related  severe    sae
subject_id                        
05-218         True    True  False
05-010         True   False  False
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('subject_id', sort=False).any().reset_index()
print (df1)
  subject_id  related  severe    sae
0     05-218     True    True  False
1     05-010     True   False  False
```